# Get position of items inside a PDF using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, math, transformation

I am using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render a PDF in a canvas with this code:

```js
const viewportScale = 1;

// Inside the PDF class is the process to load the pdf based on the library docs
const pdf = new PDF('./pdf_file.pdf');
await pdf.load();

const page = await pdf.getPage(1);

const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: viewportScale });
const canvas = document.getElementById('pdf-canvas');
canvas.width = viewport.width;
canvas.height = viewport.height;

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
await page.render({ canvasContext: ctx, viewport }).promise;
```

And it works as expected, this is the rendered PDF in the canvas:
[image]

Is a very simple PDF with only two text items, even though when doing the `page.getTextContent()` it returns three items.

```js
[
    {
        "str": "Text 1",
        "dir": "ltr",
        "width": 30.311999999999998,
        "height": 12,
        "transform": [
            12,
            0,
            0,
            12,
            175.408,
            734.384
        ],
        "fontName": "g_d0_f1",
        "hasEOL": false
    },
    {
        "str": "",
        "dir": "ltr",
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "transform": [
            12,
            0,
            0,
            12,
            346.548,
            529.101
        ],
        "fontName": "g_d0_f1",
        "hasEOL": true
    },
    {
        "str": "text 2222222",
        "dir": "ltr",
        "width": 61.12799999999999,
        "height": 12,
        "transform": [
            12,
            0,
            0,
            12,
            346.548,
            529.101
        ],
        "fontName": "g_d0_f1",
        "hasEOL": false
    }
]
```

---

What I am trying to accomplish is to detect when the mouse hovers one of the rendered items.

My goal is to do a "highlight" to those items when the mouse hovers one of them exactly as the devtools when inspecting HTML code, but the first step is to first know when the mouse hovers an item.

---

How could I get the position of each one of the elements from the `text.getTextContent()`?
X and Y position.